# How to allow non-sheet owners run scripts that involve protected cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the script below where some cells are protected because they contain formula but I can script linked to buttons that when executed, it updates the cell values in these protected cells, this is fine if you are the sheet owner but if you are not you get a error saying 'You are editing protected cells....'

I have seen some solutions where the script has been deployed as a web app and then set so it always runs as the owner but can't get this working for my use case, I deployed and set as to always run as me but this only seems like half the solution?

My code is below:

```
//

// Save Data
function submitData() {
 
 var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Data";
 var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
 var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;
    
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Tool"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
  
  var str       = formSS.getRange("A10").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] != str ) {
        //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' "Dmp #' + formSS.getRange("A4").getValue() + '  "');
       // return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];

    //} else  {

     //Input Values
     var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("A10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("H10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("K10").getValue()]];

     var values2 = [[formSS.getRange("A10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("K10").getValue()]];


    values2[0].forEach(function(val) {
   if (val === "") { 
     throw new Error("Please fill in Project, Category, Subsystem, Description and Created By Fields.");
    }
})           
   
     // Save New Data
     
     datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 11).setValues(values1);
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' New Record Created ');
  
    
     formSS.getRange("D10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("E10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("F10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("G10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("H10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("I10").clearContent();
     formSS.getRange("J10").setValue(new Date())

      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
 
  }
}
//=========================================================

// Clear form

function clearCell() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Tool"); //Form Sheet
  
    
  
  formSS.getRange("D10").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("E10").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("F10").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("G10").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("I10").clearContent();
  formSS.getRange("J10").setValue(new Date())
  return true ;
  
}

//=====================================================================

var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Data";
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;

function searchStr() {
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Tool"); //Form Sheet
  
  var str       = formSS.getRange("F4").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
     
      
      formSS.getRange("A6").setValue(row[0]) ;
      formSS.getRange("B6").setValue(row[1]);
      formSS.getRange("C6").setValue(row[2]);
      formSS.getRange("D6").setValue(row[3]);
      formSS.getRange("E6").setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("F6").setValue(row[5]);
      formSS.getRange("G6").setValue(row[6]);
      formSS.getRange("H6").setValue(row[7]);
      formSS.getRange("I6").setValue(row[8]);
      formSS.getRange("J6").setValue(row[9]);
      
           
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
      
    }
  }
}

//===================================================================

function rowDelete() {
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Tool"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
 
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert(
  'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 // Process the user's response.
 if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
   
   var str       = formSS.getRange("F4").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
    var  INT_R = i+1
      
    datasheet.deleteRow(INT_R) ;
      
    formSS.getRange("A6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("B6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("C6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("D6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("E6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("F6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("G6").clearContent();
    formSS.getRange("H6").clearContent(); 
    formSS.getRange("I6").clearContent(); 
    formSS.getRange("J6").clearContent(); 
      
     return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
    
  }
 } 
  
}

//====================================================================

function updateData() {

  var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Data";
  var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
  var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;
  
   var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Tool"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
  
 
  var str       = formSS.getRange("A6").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
     var INT_R = i+1
      formSS.getRange("J6").setValue(new Date())
      
      var values1 = [[formSS.getRange("A6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("H6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J6").getValue()]];

      var values2 = [[formSS.getRange("A6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("E6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("F6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("G6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("I6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("J6").getValue()]];

                 values2[0].forEach(function(val) {
   if (val === "") { 
     throw new Error("Please fill in Revisions, Project, Category, Subsystem, Description and Updated By Fields.");
    }
}) 
datasheet.getRange(INT_R, 1, 1, 10).setValues(values1);
                  formSS.getRange("A6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("B6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("C6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("D6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("E6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("F6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("G6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("H6").clearContent(); 
                  formSS.getRange("I6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("J6").clearContent();
                  formSS.getRange("E4").clearContent();
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(' Record Updated ');
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Deploying as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) involves creating a separate HTML UI apart from the sheet that users visit on an address like `https://script.google.com/.../exec`. It doesn't look like your code has a `doGet()` or an html page so you may have misunderstood the way it works. The Web App uses your authorization so it would allow other users to edit unprotected cells, but if you don't want to redirect users away from the spreadsheet, you're probably better off toggling protection with a trigger like in Martin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several posts about this, I'll paste a response from one from yesterday. What I recommend specifically in your case is to run the script when there's an edit bye the user in a certain cell. For example a Tickbox, or a Drop-down menu (in a cell) that allows the user to select which function to run:

If you already have an onEdit function working, that's a simple trigger run by whoever is editing the sheet. Meaning that  if you protect column A, it won't be editable by that simple trigger because the user won't have permissions

In order to work this out, I encourage you to protect your column as explained [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656%3Fhl%3Den%26co%3DGENIE.Platform%253DDesktop&ved=2ahUKEwiziv2S9o78AhWcrJUCHTpkDeEQFnoECBQQBQ&usg=AOvVaw0W4bzu7lHVbuellfa20zWF), change your name function or extract in a new function the part about this specific code you're talking about; and set an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that runs on event. This way it'll be run as you used to but as it came from your own account. As you have permissions for editing ColA the timestamp will be set by the installable trigger but the other user won't be able to edit it since he/she doesn't have the permissions. Try it and let me know!